# Setting a Default SSRS parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, default, ssrs-2008-r2

Default SSRS Settings.  I have several parameters, some are interdependent on each other.

For example:

There is `season` parameter, `final`, and then i have a `user` parameter.

The `final` field is `Yes or No.`

The `user` output depends on the `year`

If my `year` is `2019`, i will only see the users that are active for that year.

```
select distinct user where year = @year
```

I need to set defaults:

season needs to be `max(year)` how do i select max possible value?

`final`, options are `yes or no`, on the server we select '`N`' 
to be default. (see graphic below)

[image]

But with the users we want to select `'Select All'` as a default based on the year. I don't know how to get the default to be a 'select all' possible options based on the query/year.

Comment: Can't you just set the default to something like `=Year(Today())`?  This would set the default to the current year.

Comment: @Steve-o169 theoretically, that could work although my question still stands about where i specify the default. But the data all comes from a table of data, and the values (seasons) are entered for year or two in the future so it has years 2020, 2021 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can not achieve this from report manager unless it is defined in the report.

E.g. for season, you need to define the default from a dataset, and create a dataset with the SQL to SELECT MAX(year).

Comment: Where do i specify the max(year), on the server like I did with final? building a data-set is complex its where/how do i set the default up. What about the select all default for users.

Comment: You can only do it in the development environment like SSDT. Open the report project, and update the report. You can not achieve this after the report is deployed to the server

Comment: I tried setting up the defaults there, but they don't seem to transfer over to the server. Any suggestions of what to try/where to look for ideas.

Comment: You need to deploy the updated report to the server.